# Splice() method removes end of array not at index

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof, array-splice

My function `removeItems()` is to remove items from a list item within a li element. Currently I can remove the item from the view but the array splice method removes the element from the end of the array and not at index.

my code is:

```
var data = [
    "Tuesday ",
    "Wednesday",
    "Thursday",
    "Friday",
    "Saturday", 
    "Sunday"
];

function itemArray(ele) {
    let items = ''; 
    for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        items += `<li>${ele[i]} <button type='button' class='removeItem'>Remove Item</button> </li>`;
    }
    return items;
}

function addItemFunction () {
    const addButton = document.getElementById('addButton');
    const input = document.getElementById('input').value;
    data.push(input);    
    htmlInside(data);  
}

function removeItemFunction() {
    data.pop(data);    
    htmlInside(data);
}

function removeItems() {
    const listUl = main.querySelector('ul');
    listUl.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        if (event.target.tagName == 'BUTTON') {
          let li = event.target.parentNode;
          let ul = li.parentNode;
          ul.removeChild(li);
          var index = data.indexOf(data);
          data.splice(index, 1);
          console.log(data);
        }
      });
}

function htmlInside(data) {
        let getHtml = `
    <ul class="listItems">
        ${itemArray(data)}
        
    </ul>
    <input type='input' id='input' required></input><button type='button' id='addButton'>Add item</button><button id='removeButton'>Remove item</button>
    
    `
    document.querySelector('.hero').innerHTML = getHtml;

    addButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        addItemFunction();
    });

    removeButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        removeItemFunction();
    });

    removeItems();

 }
```

I don't think I am finding the index of the data correctly. Might be an issue at `var index = data.indexOf(this); data.splice(index, 1);`

when I `console.log(index)` its logs -1.

Comment: The second argument to splice is how many elements to remove.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Comment: it is removing the correct amount which is 1

Comment: `data.indexOf(data);` <= ok this is weird.  How can an element be contained within itself? Other than something like `var x = []; x.push(x);`

Comment: Yes, so I am sure I am not getting the index correctly... have not done much with indexOf

Comment: So trying to read through this.  It looks like your intent is that when a button is clicked, that you remove one of the value from the data.  Is that accurate?

Comment: That is accurate

Comment: So what is the relationship between the button, and the value that needs to be removed?

Comment: Essentially its like a todo app, you can add to the data array and should be able to remove an item from the list also, so adding is pushing to the array and there is a pop method which removes the last element from the array and this splice method should remove the element in the list which corresponds to the array

Comment: Right, but what I'm saying is, it looks like you have something like `<li>(value here)<button to remove value></li>`.  So as far as I can tell from just the quick browsing, other than having to find the li that the button was in to then dig down into the text of that element to grab the value, you do not have an easy way to know what value to use.  Instead if you made a change to say, perhaps add the value on the remove button as a data attribute, then you could just refer to that on the button that is clicked to know what to remove.

Comment: `indexOf` returns -1 if the element is not found, probable `this` is not what you expect

Comment: I mean I am open to a correct way of doing it with an explanation, this was just my attempt at it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line `var index = data.indexOf(data)` you are checking the index of the data ,you should check the index of the element in the data array so you should first get that element from the list with something like  `ele=li.textContent` and then pass it to `data.indexOf(ele)`

Comment: so I should be looking for the <li></li> element, then pass that into indexOf? but shouldn't the splice method remove from the array directly?

Comment: yes it should but it removes by passing the index of the element you want to remove and how many elements you want to remove starting from that index , and in your case you are passing the indexof the array not the element in the array, so what you should be doing is when you press the remove button get the textContent from the list this will be the element that you want to delete from the array so therefore you check the indexOf the textContent of the targeted list. does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, however I have changed adjusted the code as per your suggestion: to `var ele = li.textContent;var index = data.indexOf(ele);console.log(ele); data.splice(index, 1);` So the console logs the correct item selected, however the splice is still removing the item from the end of the array.

Comment: I have recreated at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-junbyl

Comment: the issues  in your code are 2 first the `li.textContent` returns the name of the day and some extra text so i just extracted the name of the day from the string and second problem is that in your data array the day Tuesday has some extra space in it so I fixed all that   here is working code [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-rey9ov?file=index.js)

Comment: ahhh the extra space - my bad. So when getting the index of something you need the element by itself nothing extra, otherwise it won't work? so why did you use the `Split a string into an array of substrings` method?

Comment: Yes that's correct, the reason I split the string is to extract the day from string , you can use any other method you want to achieve the same thing you can use slice or substring or regex but the most efficient one for this case I believe is a split. Let me know if you have anymore questions

Answer (score 0):

In the click event listener, `console.log` the value returned by `data.splice(index, 1)`. What you should see is -1. Now if you place -1 into a splice it start from the end backwards, in this case the last element and removes that.

This is because the `.indexOf` method returns -1 when nothings' found, which is the case here.